# Is it possible to detect when a user switches tabs?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser, firefox-addon

In particular, I am interested to know if it is possible to capture a user's click to a different browser tab. I guess technically I could get the blur and focus of the window object but if there was something more closely tied to the browser (IE, FF, Chrome, etc.) that would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IE**

If you are writing native code (i.e. a browser plug-in) you can use [DWebBrowserEvents2::WindowStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768358%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Here is some sample code, for your `IDispatch::Invoke()` implementation:

```
    // DWebBrowserEvents2
    case DISPID_WINDOWSTATECHANGED: {
        if (pDispParams) {
            DWORD dwMask  = pDispParams->rgvarg[0].lVal;
            DWORD dwFlags = pDispParams->rgvarg[1].lVal;

            // We only care about WINDOWSTATE_USERVISIBLE.
            if (dwMask & OLECMDIDF_WINDOWSTATE_USERVISIBLE)
            {
                bool visible = !!(dwFlags & OLECMDIDF_WINDOWSTATE_USERVISIBLE));

                // ... your code here ...
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

There is no explicit event sent to the Javascript of the page, but the blur event may do what you desire.

**Firefox**

In Firefox you can detect tab changes in your XUL by adding an event listener for `TabAttrModified` and inspecting the `selected` attribute.  See the [MDC documentation for the dealing with the Tabbed Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Notification_when_a_tab%27s_attributes_change).

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I am currently writing plugins for IE, Chrome, and FF and needed something like this. Is it possible to do this in Chrome or FF as well?

Comment: It is certainly possible to do it Firefox (see edit in my answer).  I believe it to be possible in Chrome, but I've never done it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great start.

Comment: In Firefox, listening for `TabSelect` is simpler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_tab_selection