# Detect android browser tab switch

Tags: android, browser, tabs, contentobserver

I would like to detect when a user switches tabs within the native Android web browser (other web browsers would be a plus).  Is there an event that gets raised when this occurs that an outside app can trap or would I have to create my own application with a web view inside if and detect this from within my own custom browser?

I researched the following but to no avail.  They were not very relevant to my goal:

[Switching tabs but not very Android-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716115/is-it-possible-to-detect-when-a-user-switches-tabs)

[Tab-related activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643226/android-changing-tab-visibility-from-inside-tab-activities)

[Switching tabs in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959235/using-android-browser-detecting-page-change)

My goal is to determine how much time a user spends viewing a particular web page before navigating away or leaving the app completely.

Comment: This is the latest answer I have come up with so far.  It looks like I may have to go the custom route:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/sCq2_PXhgUU

Comment: use the window blur event handling : http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/taRG6/

Comment: That looks like a javascript solution.  Can I use that from within a separate application?  I need to monitor the web browser externally and not from a webpage opened within the browser itself.

Comment: Yea it is.  I dont think you can track the actual browser itself regardless of site visited. I was thinking this was for one website that you have ability to add JS code to run heatmap/visit-time monitoring.

Comment: @forgivegod No, I need to externally monitor browser use for statistical purposes.

Comment: Theres no event to lookout for that I could find via the logs.  Would probably fall under a security flaw if you could very easily.

Comment: I figured as much.  Which logs are you looking at?  Do you know of any way to "hook" into the OS to monitor these events if you were able to build your own ROM image and not worry so much about security?